# how do i read mifare classic tag first sector value?

Tags: android

On my Main Activity i have to show the first sector block value of Mi-fare classic tag. when i hold new tag at mobile at that time app also show tag information.
In my app i have to show only one activity.so please tell me how it is possible.
Yet i tried all the tutorial but not getting proper info.
My manifest code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.samplecode"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.nfc"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.samplecode.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

               <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"
                 android:resource="@xml/nfc_tech_filter"/>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: You can start from [this example](https://github.com/nadam/nfc-reader)

Comment: please comment link of your example@Batuhan

Comment: i want first sector value